# How can i add a usercontrol (a LongListSelector) in Application bar in Win Phone8 ?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have a situation wherein i need to add a UserControl ("LongListSelector") in Application bar.
I dont seem to find a way to implement that.
Is it even possible ?

using C# +XAML + Win Phone 8

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible.

Here's the correct use of the ApplicationBar:http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/06/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-6-application-bar/

Comment: Alright but how can i achieve whats there in Nokia Maps app when you tap on "Places" menu button.It makes the app bar go away and adds a similar view which can be swiped up and down and has a LongListSelector in it.

Comment: They are not using the application bar for that. It is a custom user control